# Using Paginate with constructed query in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, will-paginate

I'm trying to do something along the following lines:

```
if start_date?
  query = where("datetime > :start_date", :start_date => start_date)
end

if end_date?
  query = where("datetime <= :end_date", :end_date => end_date)
end

if client
  query = where("client.name LIKE :client", :client => client)
end

if staff
  query = where("staff.name LIKE :staff", :staff => staff)
end

paginate :per_page => 20, :page => page,
           :conditions => query,
           :order => 'datetime'
```

I can't find any examples though of how to build up a query and use it along with paginate plugin. Of course the query isn't correct yet as I've got to figure out how to do the joins so I can query against the other properties in other tables, but other than that, how do you build up queries to use in the conditions?

Answer (score 4):

You want to put the `.paginate` call on the end of the chain of where calls, like this (all one line, split up for readability)

```
SomeClass.where("datetime > :start_date", :start_date=>start_date).
  where("datetime < :end_date", :end_date=>end_date).
  paginate(:per_page=>20,:page=>page)
```

If you want to conditionally add the conditions, you can do that too, like:

```
x = SomeClass
x = x.where("datetime > :start_date", :start_date=>start_date) if start_date
x = x.where("datetime < :end_date", :end_date=>end_date) if end_date
x.paginate(:per_page=>20,:page=>page)
```

Comment: This is the way to do, one thing I would add is `x = SomeClass.scoped` or if you are within your model just do `x = scoped`.

Comment: I saw some articles on scoped, I wasn't sure if it was applicable in my case though

Comment: I'll triple check it's correct when I get home this evening, my project's on my home machine so I'll mark this correct if so

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if you installed kaminari gem :

```
ModelName.where( your_query ).page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord Relation doesn't have paginate method

Answer (score 0):

.where() returns ActiveRecord::Relation

.paginate()'s :conditions parameter has to be an array of conditions as if it was an argument of .where().

You should fix your code as next:

```
if start_date?
  query = ["datetime > :start_date", :start_date => start_date]
end
```

etc.

Comment: How can you build up a query doing this though? Can you just concatenate these together?

Comment: query = ["datetime > :start_date", :start_date => start_date]; paginate :per_page => 20, :page => page, :conditions => query, :order => 'datetime'